# Python / Bokeh - FuncTickFormatter

Tags: python, bokeh

> EDIT: thanks to @tmwilson26 I was able to fix it using `javascript code`(see comments below). However, I would still be interested to know if there is a solution using `from_py_func`.

I am using Bokeh and struggling to format my axis using `FuncTickFormatter`.

Specifically I am using the `FuncTickFormatter.from_py_func` function.

My below code example doesn't produce any result (but also no error message).

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource,Label, FuncTickFormatter,DatetimeTickFormatter,NumeralTickFormatter, Select, FixedTicker, Slider,TableColumn,DatePicker, DataTable, TextInput, HoverTool,Range1d,BoxZoomTool, ResetTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox, layout
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, push_notebook, show

output_notebook()

x = np.arange(10)
y = [random.uniform(0,5000) for el in x]

xfactors = list("abcdefghi")

yrange = Range1d(0,5000)

p = figure(x_range = xfactors, y_range = yrange,y_minor_ticks = 10)
p.circle(x,y, size = 14, line_color = "grey" , fill_color = "lightblue", fill_alpha = 0.2)


def ticker():    
    a = '{:0,.0f}'.format(tick).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", ".") 
    return a

# If I comment below line out, code is running just fine
p.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter.from_py_func(ticker)

show(p)
```

If I comment the FuncTickFormatter line out the code is just running fine. Also the defined function `ticker` works if I use it outside this code.

Any advice on what I am doing wrong would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Right now, `tick` is not defined anywhere in the program in the inner scope of `ticker` or in the main outer scope.  Should `tick` be an input argument for `ticker`?

Comment: Yes, I know. But the way I understand the documentation I don't have to define it (see [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#functickformatter). Obviously I didn't get it fully right though...

Comment: Perhaps my version doesn't like it, because it returns `ValueError: Function "func" can have only one argument, but 0 were supplied.` if I don't define `tick` as an input.  That being said, the plot is still blank unless I reformat your string using `%` instead of the `format` method.

Comment: Defining `a` as follows returns a plot, but I'm not sure if this is what you want: `a = ('%f' % tick).replace(",", "X").replace(".", ",").replace("X", ".")`.  Perhaps you can alter this to suit your application.  Obviously, the y-scale in this case returns only numbers, and your replace functions don't do anything, but it at least plots something.

Comment: @tmwilson26 thanks for your help. If I replace my function with your it produces a plot. However, it is exactly the same plot as if I would not use my FuncTickFormatter function. So unfortunately it doesn't improve my code. Actually I am only trying to convert a number using "." as decimals and "," as digits. So e.g. convert 5000 in 5.000,0. Any other idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: You could consider trying to use straight Javascript code, because the problem seems to be in trying to convert the Python code to Javascript.  I'll see if I can't put together an example and post it as an answer.

Comment: FYI, the FuncTickFormatter is deprecated in favour of CustomJSTickFormatter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `from_py_func` is giving you trouble, try using straight Javascript.  Here is an example below:

```
p.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    function(tick){
        function markCommas(x) {
            return x.toFixed(1).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "X");
        }
        return markCommas(tick).replace('.',',').replace("X",'.')
    }
""")
```

In some of the documentation, it might not need you to define a function with `tick` as an input argument, so you may need to remove that outer function, but on my version `0.12.2`, this works to produce numbers like you asked for, e.g. 5.000,0

In the newer version, it might look something like this:

```
p.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    function markCommas(x) {
        return x.toFixed(1).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "X");
    }
    return markCommas(tick).replace('.',',').replace("X",'.')
""")
```

If the sub-function doesn't work, here is a one-line return statement:

```
p.yaxis.formatter = FuncTickFormatter(code="""
    return tick.toFixed(1).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "X").replace('.',',').replace("X",'.');
""")
```

Comment: Is this working on your system. For me it is not working - neither in `jupyter` nor using `bokeh serve`. Same as before: No error message, no plot...

Comment: Yeah, it is.  I have an older version of bokeh though (latest is 0.12.4 and I have 0.12.2), which I hoped would not be a problem, but alas.  Try to remove the outer function.  I'll update my answer with that formatting so that you can see, but I can't test that on my version, so let me know if that works.

Comment: If that doesn't work, I suspect it will be because of the sub-function definition, which can be removed if need be.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help. Now it works. I will still leave the question open as maybe someone knows why the python version doesn't work.

Comment: No problem.  That sounds good.  I'd be interested to know what the problem with the conversion is.  One bad thing about these Javascript libraries is that javascript won't give the traceback like the Python code will.